# Set quality video record desktop screen windows media encoder 9 SDK

Tags: c#, windows-media-encoder

I use windows media encoder 9 SDK in C# to `record desktop screen`. But video quality is bad.

How to set video's quality?

Here's my code:

```
WMEncoderApp DesktopEncoderAppln = new WMEncoderApp();
DesktopEncoder = DesktopEncoderAppln.Encoder;
IWMEncSourceGroupCollection SrcGroupCollection = DesktopEncoder.SourceGroupCollection;
IWMEncSourceGroup SrcGroup = SrcGroupCollection.Add("SG_1");
IWMEncVideoSource2 VideoSrc = (IWMEncVideoSource2)SrcGroup.AddSource(WMENC_SOURCE_TYPE.WMENC_VIDEO);
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you create a pre-defined WM profile, where you can set your quality requirements, and in your C# code, load the so created profile with all the predefined settings using

```
WMEncProfile2()
```

Please look up the SDK documentation for more info abt using WMEncProfile2

Hope this helps.